# Centos7, after yum update, failed to start mysql, Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: mysql

Centos7, after yum update, failed to start mysql, Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

```
2022-12-16T12:58:19.282332Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31) starting as process 26674

2022-12-16T12:58:25.301579Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.

2022-12-16T12:58:27.128343Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012961] [InnoDB] Only one redo log file found

2022-12-16T12:58:27.731530Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.

2022-12-16T12:58:32.651405Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine

2022-12-16T12:58:34.620668Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.

2022-12-16T12:58:35.416630Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2022-12-16T12:58:41.840762Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

please help.

Comment: Its best to post textual information as text rather than image.

Comment: thanks, change already. @Rohit Gupta